# firebase_messaging/failed-service-worker-registration Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker

Tags: flutter, dart

**Error**

**Messaging:** We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:54558/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:54558/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed .

I have tried everything including firebase-messaging-sw.js and index.html but not sending text message on the web-page. **Please help**. Trying to fix it but not getting FCM messaging text.

**Firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-messaging.js");
// const firebaseConfig = {
//     apiKey: "AIzaSyAzWCmRI_hR6lXsRDEJMtpo89BTw9r27OA",
//     authDomain: "matabwebadmin.firebaseapp.com",
//     projectId: "matabwebadmin",
//     storageBucket: "matabwebadmin.appspot.com",
//     messagingSenderId: "104162661195",
//     appId: "1:104162661195:web:896bdc9088fd54884b4ece"
//   };


  Firebase.initializeApp({
    //    name: "matabmaindatabase",
  apiKey:"AIzaSyAzWCmRI_hR6lXsRDEJMtpo89BTw9r27OA",
  appId: '1:104162661195:web:896bdc9088fe54884b4ece',
  messagingSenderId: "104162661195",
  projectId: "matabwebadmin",
  storageBucket: "matabwebadmin.appspot.com",
  });
  
const messaging = firebase.messaging();




if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('../firebase-messaging-sw.js')
      .then(function(registration) {
        console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err);
      });
    }
```

**Index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="matabweb">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>matabweb</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

    



<script>
  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
      // navigator.serviceWorker.register("/flutter_service_worker.js");
      navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
    });
  }
  </script>

<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register("firebase-messaging-sw.js");
    });
  
    window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
    });
  }
  </script>


  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function(engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function(appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Main.dart:**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  const firebaseConfig = {
    "apiKey": "AIzaSyAzWCmRI_hR6lXsRDEJMtpo89BTw9r27OA",
    "authDomain": "matabwebadmin.firebaseapp.com",
    "projectId": "matabwebadmin",
    "storageBucket": "matabwebadmin.appspot.com",
    "messagingSenderId": "104162661195",
    "appId": "1:104162661195:web:896bdc9088fd54884b4ece"
  };
  FirebaseApp app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
      //    name: "matabmaindatabase",
      options: FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: FirebaseConfiurations.apiKey,
    appId: FirebaseConfiurations.appId,
    messagingSenderId: FirebaseConfiurations.messagingSenderId,
    projectId: FirebaseConfiurations.projectId,
    storageBucket: "matabwebadmin.appspot.com",
  ));
  //print(app);

  // FirebaseApp app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
  //     name: 'matabweb',
  //     options: const FirebaseOptions(
  //         appId: '1:104162661195:web:896bdc9088fd54884b4ece',
  //         apiKey: 'AIzaSyAzWCmRI_hR6lXsRDEJMtpo89BTw9r27OA',
  //         messagingSenderId: '104162661195',
  //         projectId: 'matabwebadmin'));
  debugPrint(app.toString());
  // Get.put(BookController(), tag: 'bookController');
  // Get.lazyPut(() => UserController(), tag: 'userController');

  runApp(MyApp());
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((print));
}
```

Comment: I think service workers are only served over https://